# How to make a list of binary numbers

Tags: c++, random

I want to have a function to make a list of binary random numbers.. I don't know which method is appropriate for this purpose. I can make it with an array , a while command, linked list or a std ..

I want to return the whole list from the function. In array i think i can't do that. For example the following function only return the first elements.

```
long int  SourceNode::database(long int chunk_var[])
{
    srand ( time(0) );
    for(int j = 0; j<50 ;j++)
    {
        int myrand = rand() % 2 ;
        myrand = myrand & 0x3ff;
        chunk_var[j]= myrand;
    }
    return *chunk_var;
}
```

i want something to return the whole list, because i want to invoke that function( the whole list) in another function . is there any alternative solution instead of making an array?

Comment: The result of `rand() % 2` is going to be either `0` or `1`. That's all you get "modulo 2". `myrand = myrand & 0x3ff` won't do anything for you at that point, so I'm not sure why you have that.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>`?  `boost::dynamic_bitset`?

Comment: As you use 50 values, you may use an `std::uint64_t` and use bit masking/shifting for the wanted value.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `vector<bool>` or a `vector<uint32_t>`.  That will be easier than any other option.  BTW, C++11 added a new [random number generator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that is friendlier *and* probably uses a better underlying algorithm than `rand`.

Comment: " probably uses a better underlying algorithm than `rand` " you can remove "probably"

Comment: @Amxx Many do use a crappy LCRNG, but there's nothing that _prevents_ a C library from using MT19337 or ChaCha or something even better to implement `rand`.  (I find the explicit specification of algorithms in `std::random` to be somewhat unfortunate.)

Comment: My vision is that you either know what you need, and then use a specific generator in `std::radom` or you just don't know what you do and use `rand()`.

`rand()` is as bad as the worst generator that may be used below it ... `std::rand` enables you to control the generator, and control is ALWAYS better

Comment: thanks a'lot, does it makes binary random numbers too ?

Comment: @farshadsoheily There is no fondamental difference difference between random numbers of different type. An `int` is juste 32 random bits. If you look at the `std::random` spec it always talk of random bits. In `std::random` you basically have generator which generates random bits, and distribution which transforms thoses random bits to `bool`/`int`/`float`/... following different distributions ...

Answer (score 0):

Just return the array you got as a parameter:

```
long int *SourceNode::database(long int chunk_var[])
{
    ......... // fill the array with numbers
    return chunk_var;
}
```

However I suppose you will also need to pass the array length to the function as another parameter so that the function knows how many items it is allowed to overwrite.

Comment: I had tried to use pointers but it didn't work . Actually i was searching to find another solution. .By the way, Thanks ;)

Comment: Actually you don't even need to return anything—once the caller allocated an array, your function needs only to fill it; the array remains where if was so there's no need to inform the calling function where it is..

Comment: You mean without returning anything it  still works?

Comment: Yes. Of course that needs changing the function declaration to `void SourceNode::database(long int chunk_var[])` or better `void SourceNode::database(long int chunk_var[], int len)` or something like that.